# Hessian matrix computation for multi-layer neural networks (from Duda's book)

Tags: pattern-recognition, neural-networks, hessian-matrix

I am reading Duda's book, Section 6.9.1, about second-order methods for multi-layer neural networks.

Considering the error criterion $J(\omega) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(t_{m}-z_{m})^{2}$, the elements of the Hessian matrix are written:
$\frac{\partial^{2}J(\omega)}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}= \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{\partial J}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial J}{\partial\omega_{lk}}+\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}})$

However, I fail to understand where the $\frac{1}{n}\partial J$ comes from as when I calculate the Hessian myself I rather come up with $\partial z_{m}$ terms instead:
$\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{lk}}+\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}$, which seems to correspond with Bishop's derivation.

Comment: $t_{m}$ and $z_m(\omega)$ ($t_{m}$ is observed, therefore I strongly believe does not depend upon $\omega$).

Comment: Also, are there extra relations between $z_m$ and $t_m$? It seems that a lot of information is missing here.

Comment: No, there is no extra relation. Some background info is indeed missing (essentially the standard construction of the whole backpropagation algorithm). This was intentional (for space reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I have to do few hypothesis since in my opinion some information is missing. As observed by Julien $t_m$ is a target function, so it is independent on $\omega$. I assume that $z_m=z_m(\omega)$. So when differentiating the error function $J(\omega)$ I have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=1}^{n}-\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{lk}}-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial z_{k}}=-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(t_{m}-z_{m}) \frac{\partial z_m}{\partial z_k}=-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(t_{m}-z_{m}) \delta_{km}= z_m-t_m
\end{equation}
Then the second derivative with respect to $z_m$ is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial z_{k}}(z_{m}-t_{m})=\delta_{km}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=1
\end{equation}
Then by multiplying and dividing by $\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}$  I can write
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=1}^{n}-\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{lk}}-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}} \frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}-\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{lk}}-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}
\end{equation}
The above expression was obtained by using the fact that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2}z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}} \frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=\frac{\partial^{2}z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}} 1 = \frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}} 
\end{equation}
When integrating with respect to $\omega$, if the integration constant is zero, we can assume that the first derivative of $J$ and that of $z_m$ with respect to $\omega$ are proportional and the proportionality factor is $1$. 
So
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=1}^{n}-\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial\omega_{lk}}-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}
= -(\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\frac{\partial J}{\partial\omega_{ji}}\frac{\partial J}{\partial\omega_{lk}}+(z_{m}-t_{m})\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial\omega_{ji}\partial\omega_{lk}}))
\end{equation}
I suspect the second term can be neglected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I did not manage to understand how you derived $\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=n
\end{equation}$, nor the reason why your integration argument yields a $\frac{1}{n}$ factor in the first summand of the RHS of the very last equation rather than $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$?

Comment: $m$ denotes the variable of the summand... what you want to compute is in fact $\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{k}^2}
\end{equation}$ (i used $k$ for clarity's sake). As a result I believe the following assertion is not valid: \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial z_{m}^2}=-\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial z_{m}}(t_{m}-z_{m})
\end{equation}

Comment: I Julien, you're right.Sorry for the mistakes.  I correct the text and add explanations.